# Google app engine Java - edit crons without redeploying app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I know that I need to set up all my crons in cron.xml file. I now want to set the schedules dynamically i.e. in a database table so that I can tweak them with a simple update. 
For example instead of having the below:

```
<cron>
  <url>/cron/task1</url>
  <description>Task 1 </description>
  <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
```

I want to have something like:

```
<cron>
  <url>/cron/task1</url>
  <description>Task 1 </description>
  <schedule>${TASK1_SCHEDULE}</schedule>
</cron>
```

where TASK1_SCHEDULE will be an entry from the database.
Is that possible ? Or is there any other way to achieve that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically modify the `cron.xml` file to accept new jobs or modifications to the list of jobs.

I agree with Martin in that you write a Cron Job that executes at the threshold interval that you can tolerate for your application i.e. 1 min or 2 minutes. In that, I would suggest manage a custom Job definition entity that contains various parameters depending on your needs, including the time for next execution.

In your Cron Job, once the time for next execution has passed, you should use a `TaskQueue` to execute the functionality, rather than running each one on our own and waiting for it to complete.

Take a look at the following article that provides a similar framework for doing so: http://pisarenko.net/blog/2013/09/03/creating-dynamic-task-scheduler-on-appengine/

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom scheduler because you cannot change cron.xml from your code.  Call your scheduler at the shortest interval you require.  Within your scheduler, query the database for tasks that are due and execute them.